# Hint to investigate some SEGFAULT no longer happening when strace-ing

Tags: linux, strace, segmentation-fault

I get an application (webcamoid in its 8.8 version) that used to be working troublefree and which now segfaults systematically at startup (kde-plasma/X11 do not even get the opportunity to open some associated window.)
Only some very short log can be found in kernel's log :

```
Sep 29 13:15:16 [kernel] [10021.734124] webcamoid[3236]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007fffffffd3c8 error 14 in webcamoid[555555554000+d000]
Sep 29 13:15:16 [kernel] [10021.734128] Code: Bad RIP value.
```

No stack dump, no core dump (the latter being probably because of my kernel configuration)

Of course I first tried running it through `strace`, but failed to get any valuable information since… the problem simply does not occur. (associated window is opened and application works normally)

I understand the immediate meaning of the logs.

1/ Does all this mean that this is a timing problem ?
2/ Is there someway using `strace` that would enable me to get more insights ?
3/ Is at the end of the day allowing core-dumps and sdb-ing the only possible path ?

---

BTW, this application is, in the same version running perfectly under my backup system, which is under some lower version of the kernel and package's dependencies.
I tried rebuilding the application from source & running some older version of the kernel (therefore v4l drivers since they are built in-kernel), downgraded level 1 package's dependencies that had been updated since (alsa-lib & gstreamer & ffmpeg) without any luck.

Of course I am aware that webcamoid_9.0 is out however upgrading is just not an option not to say that the field of this question is wider than *webcamoid*.

---

EDIT 1 : also tried with *gdb* : Same as with *strace* : No segfault, everything running just fine.

Comment: An example of a [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), I think.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : Almost certainly… however… kwin just gets no doubt that… the cat is dead… ;-)

Comment: You could run it from gdb.

Comment: @meuh : Just tried *gdb*. Same result : No segfault everything just running fine.