# Debian Sid, legacy nvidia 340.108 driver ruins running Qt software

Tags: debian, nvidia, qt, segmentation-fault

Debian Sid.

With nouveau all working good. But after installing legacy 340.108 nvidia driver for my gf9800 i have Segmentation Fault at launching all Qt GUI software. And opposite, Qt works again after uninstalling nvidia driver.

But very strange that if i run Qt soft via debugging tools such gdb or strace i have no errors.

```
gdb ./doomseeker
strace ./doomseeker
```

Same is with Qbittorrent

[image: qbtorrent]

and 2048-Qt

[image: 2084Qt]

Only one Qt application starting normally - CMake GUI and Audacious Qt theme

Segmentation fault

```
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  return 0;
}
```

Is where any solution to fix this?

Comment: Please give nouveau a try.

Comment: Qt works again after uninstalling nvidia driver

Comment: Almost certainly related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719293/hint-to-investigate-some-segfault-no-longer-happening-when-strace-ing . This happened to me (identical nvidia-driver version) right after some Qt5 upgrade. Qt apps could not find DISPLAY.

Comment: As you've resolved your issue, you should [write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) too, and drop back to accept it - you'll have to wait for 48h before accepting, tho'. This way the question is marked as solved, so it'll be useful for others down the line experiencing this kind of issue. It won't pop up in the future as "Unanswered" either.

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks. So, no solution for that?

Comment: To confirm it is indeed the same problem, can you check your kernel logs in order to confirm (infirm) that right after the segfault info, you get a line telling "Code: Bad RIP value."

Comment: Here dmesg log, after start 2048-qt
https://pastebin.com/raw/7tLqhHvr

Comment: Here yet one interesting thing. All qt soft working good at Mint 21.1 and 340.108 driver here?!

Comment: Not that surprising : AFAIK Mint-21.1 uses qt-5.15.2 while Debian sid is afaik at 5.15.8. My last troublefree version of qt was 5.15.3

Comment: Fedora 37, 340.108 nvidia driver, Qt 5.15.7 all Qt soft running well https://pastebin.com/raw/hUTsx1qW